# Parse plain text with Restkit

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, parsing, restkit

I get a response for a RestKit GET request that is just a number. It's not a JSON, not HTML, not XML. Just a plain number. For example, when I view source, here's what I see:

```
19
```

Can someone tell me how I can utilize RestKit and still parse this content?

Comment: So the get is answering data, that when rendered as a string is a number?  And the question is how to take that NSData and generate an NSNumber?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use RestKit when you can do something as simple as this

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:yourURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

the string contains the number `19`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the service is returning NSData that's a UTF8 representation of a number.  In that case...

```
NSString *resultAsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:resultAsData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber *resultAsNumber = [f numberFromString:resultAsString];
```